# Error in returning HEX values in the python code of the mouse pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, rgb, pyautogui

This code gives the instant X-Y coordinates, RGB values and HEX values of the mouse pointer. The coordinates and RGB values are correct but after sometime the hex values give the wrong result.

```
import pyautogui
import time

def print_no_newline(string):
  import sys
  sys.stdout.write("\r")
  sys.stdout.write(string)
  sys.stdout.flush()
try:
  while True:
     x, y = pyautogui.position()
     pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
     ss = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
     r = int(str(pixelColor[0]).rjust(3))
     g = int(str(pixelColor[1]).rjust(3))
     b = int(str(pixelColor[2]).rjust(3))
     hex = "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(r,g,b)
     hexstr=str(hex)
     res= ss + ' RGB: ('+ str(r) +','+ str(g) +','+ str(b) +') '+ 'HEX: '+ 
   hexstr 
     print_no_newline(res)
     time.sleep(1.0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nDone...")
```

I later even tried to clip the hexstr to return first 6 characters of hex using

```
res= ss + ' RGB: ('+ str(r) +','+ str(g) +','+ str(b) +') '+ 'HEX: '+ 
hexstr[:7]
```

but it didnt work

Sample outputs

**X:  489 Y:  622 RGB: (0,2,130) HEX: #000282eff**

**X:  545 Y:  710 RGB: (0,0,0) HEX: #000000f1f1f1**

Is it returning the garbage values from the previous position?

Answer (score 0):

You are always overwriting the same line in the console. If previous output had more characters these remain.

If you write e.g. "testing\rlook" to console it will result in "looking" because the "ing" is not overwritten.

Solution: Append enough spaces to your output.